# Is this user trolling?

Tags: discussion, users

I recently came across [Cash-](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/207341/cash), who seemingly asked the same question regarding SQL Injection over and over again. Here are the links:

- [SQLI Login Bypass Cheat-sheets Question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211242/sqli-login-bypass-cheat-sheets-question)
- ['=' 'OR' SQL Injection Login Bypass Question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211160/or-sql-injection-login-bypass-question)
- [' OR 1=1/* SQL Injection Login Bypass Question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/210038/or-1-1-sql-injection-login-bypass-question)
- [SQL injection authentication bypass](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/209817/sql-injection-authentication-bypass)

Is this considered trolling or should we assume he acts in good faith and just has trouble understanding the basics? And if the assumption is that he is trolling, how should we proceed with those questions? Flag as dupe and downvote?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, flag or vote to close as duplicate - try to assume best intentions rather than trolling.

We'll have a look wider just in case, but the community can at least close these easily.